# I'm trying to read the data from the files in the directory as soon as a new file is created. Real time "File Streaming"

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm currently learning spark-streaming. I'm trying to read the data from the files in the directory as soon as a new file is created. Real time "File Streaming". I'm getting the below error. Can anyone suggest me a solution?

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

object FileStreaming {
    def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
        val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]")
        val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))
        val lines = ssc.textFileStream("C:\\Users\\PRAGI V\\Desktop\\data-
        master\\data-master\\cards")
        lines.flatMap(x => x.split(" ")).map(x => (x, 1)).print()
        ssc.start()
        ssc.awaitTermination()
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: An application 
name must be set in your configuration     
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext. <init>(SparkContext.scala:170)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.createNewSparkContext(StreamingContext.scala:555)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>
(StreamingContext.scala:75)
at FileStreaming$.main(FileStreaming.scala:15)
at FileStreaming.main(FileStreaming.scala)
```

Comment: The error is as clear as possible and suggest you to put a name for the application in your spark configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear, you need to set app name in spark conf objet.

Replace

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]”)
```

to

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]”).setAppName(“MyApp")
```

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest to read official [Spark Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html)

The first thing a Spark program must do is to create a SparkContext object, which tells Spark how to access a cluster. Only one SparkContext may be active per JVM. You must stop() the active SparkContext before creating a new one.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)
new SparkContext(conf)
```

> The appName parameter is a name for your application to show on the
>   cluster UI. master is a Spark, Mesos or YARN cluster URL, or a special
>   “local” string to run in local mode.

Online documentation have lot of examples to get started.

Cheers !